# What is the difference between enum keyword in C# and C?

Tags: c#, c, enums

May I know what is the difference between `enum` keyword in C# and C?

I tried to use the `enum` variables in c style in C#, But I was getting error. When I searched Google it said, if we have enum Days {Sat, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri}; then we need to use Days.Sat in C# instead of Sat directly like in C. Why is it so?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type#C.23 read it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the designers of C# thought it is better to have the enum values enclosed in its own "namespace" instead of throwing them all into the parent namespace. Many people think this is an annoyance in C / C++.
BTW, in C++11 there are "strongly typed enums" now, with a syntax very similar to that of C#:

```
enum class Day
{
    Mon,
    Tue,
};

Day myDay = Day::Mon;
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply: because that is the way the two **different** languages are specified. In C, the names are scoped at the declaring level, where-as in C# the names are subordinate to the enum type. The latter approach helps avoid both ambiguity and conflict:

- to the reader, is it obvious that `Sat` means the "day of the week"? why not the "body position"? or the "admissions exam"?
- what happens when multiple enums declare the same name in different contexts, potentially with different values?
- it also makes for better IDE tooling support - showing just the appropriate options

But "why is it so?" is simply: *because that is the way each language is designed*.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, enums and properties are first-class members of the language, fully supported by the underlying engine, as are events and delegates (type-safe function pointers).
In C#,  an enum is traded like a class with some exceptions, meaning it can be declared at the namespace or class level; it cannot be defined in a statement block within a method as it can in C++. If you try, Visual Studio issues an error not about the enum definition itself, but instead at the opening brace of the method, stating '} expected' rather than something useful like 'enum cannot be defined at statement level' or even 'invalid statement'. Another unintuitive error message brought to you courtesy of Microsoft.

I have got this information form the following links:

http://suncat-csharp.blogspot.de/2010/11/differences-between-enum-in-c-and-cc.html

http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/446478-Enum-C-vs-C

I hope this will help you to understand the differences. A lot of other small things I will ist it to you later!

Answer (score 1):

In C and C++, an enum defines a value type that represents a restricted set of values. 
An enum type can be declared just about anywhere before it is used, including statement blocks.

In C#,  an enum defines a class (i.e. types are classes), meaning it can be declared only at the namespace or class level;
 it cannot be defined in a statement block within a method as it can in C++.

please go through this link,

http://cplus.about.com/od/introductiontoprogramming/p/enumeration.htm